# IBM SAS RAID Controller: POST results not complete

Tags: ibm, bladecenter

I have two IBM SAS RAID Controllers (17P9277/43W3630).  One of them will not POST and fails with the error:

```
POST results not complete: FF
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Buy a new one. Seriously. That is a low level error. Pull it, replace it, test it and send it in for warranty.